# CSS different font for styles that make text bold

Tags: html, css

I am using a monospace font in my HTML project, and I don't like how the font looks when it's bold. However, I still need bold text for emphasis and headers, and because I also want the font to be different on all elements that use bold, like `strong`, `h1`, `h2`, etc. And any others that I add bold text in CSS. Is there a way to change the font, only for elements that have bold text?

Comment: try using font-weight property

Comment: It depends what your reffering to. CSS will try to manipulate the font themself when there is no style variant available. Just import the correct style for that deserved input. If it's available entry depends on the font: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Code+Pro?category=Monospace#standard-styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common tags like `b`, `strong` and headings are styled by the browsers default stylesheet. You have to overwrite them by your own.

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
b,
strong {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: You can also use @font-face if you want to overwrite it specifically for that font-family.